# Benacerraf's identification problem and PA categoricity

Tags: logic, philosophy

Lately I have been interested in mathematical philosophy, and especially structuralism.

In this setting, [Benacerraf's famous paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Philosophy-of-mathematics%3A-What-numbers-could-not-Benacerraf/1a658c2504d0d59c72394b46602e1535d3b7ff98) is a classic and works as follows:
Take the Zermelo ordinals ($x \to \{x\}$) and the Von Neumann ordinals ($x \to x \cup \{x\}$), those two are models of First order Peano Arithmetic $PA$, but they do not give the same answer to the sentence $1 \in 3$ (respectively false and true).

Benacerraf uses this to then conclude that when talking about numbers, one cannot do anything appart from talking of a given number *in relation with the others*, as a so-called *structure*.

On the other hand, $PA$ is not categorical: there exists multiple classes of models up to isomorphism.

The question is thus the following: is Benacerraf's identification problem specific to the fact that $PA$ is not categorical ?

Comment: The Zermelo vs. von Neumann example doesn’t have to do with categoricity, since they are isomorphic models.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Then from what I understand my question is not relevant in the end  ?

Comment: I was inspired by your question to read the entry on mathematical structuralism in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/. The issue you raise comes up repeatedly, with way too many subtleties to get into here.

Comment: I’m finding it hard to imagine an answer to your question that wouldn’t be mostly the writers’ opinions. Maybe try the philosophy stackexchange? They have a tag philosophy-of-mathematics.

Comment: Oh great yeah, I'll try that. Though after some thinking, both ordinals defined above are also models of second order PA, which is categorical, so I'd say that I missed the point